# Vim: creating a C string literal around a block of text with vertically aligned quotes?

Tags: vim

I would like to create a macro or a script in Vim that does the following:

1. wrap a block of text in double quotes
2. escaping any quotes that appear in the text itself
3. have the quotes on the right side in vertical alignment

For example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>High Score Server</h1>
<table>
ROWS
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

would become:

```
"<html>                    "
"<head></head>             "
"<body>                    "
"<h1>High Score Server</h1>"
"<table>                   "
"ROWS                      "
"</table>                  "
"</body>                   "
"</html>                   ";
```

I am able to achieve this with a macro, but without the vertical alignment of the quotes on the right side. Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'd do :

With "surround" and "Align" plugins :

1) with cursor on first line (0,0), type `<C-V>)$s"`
2) then `<S-V>):Align "` and `<Enter>`.

**Another solution without plugins :**

1) set virtual mode

```
:set ve=all
```

2) `<C-V>` to go in block-wise selection, with cursor at the position 0,0

3) go down to the bottom of the text, then `Shift-I`, type `"` and `Esc`. This should prepend the quotes.

4) now go on the left end (since ve=all, you can go where there is no text)
5) `<C-V>`, go down to bottom, type `r"`

This is long to explain, but easy to do and reproduce. Also useful in lots of case.

Comment: The second solution is awesome!

Comment: +1 for `virtualedit`, I thought there was a built-in feature that would do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
function Enquote()
    let [startline, endline]=sort([line("'<"), line("'>")])
    let lines=getline(startline, endline)
    let lengths=map(copy(lines), 'len(split(v:val, ''\zs''))')
    let maxlen=max(lengths)
    call map(lines, '''"''.v:val.repeat(" ", maxlen-lengths[v:key]).''"''')
    return setline(startline, lines)
endfunction
```

Explanation:

`line("'<")` and `line("'>")` get the line numbers of start and end of last visual selection.

`sort([...])` sorts this line numbers since you may have started selecting lines from the end of the selection.

`let [a, b]=[c, d]` is a parallel assignment: `sort` will produce a sorted list of two items, where first item is lesser or equal to second item. Obviously, lesser is a first selected line.

`len(split(v:val, '\zs'))` is an advanced `strlen()` which supports unicode.

`max(list)` finds a maximum value. Obvious.

So, `map(copy(lines), 'len(split(v:val, ''\zs''))')` applies this `strlen` to all items in list. `copy()` is required since we do not want our list to be modified.

`map(lines, '''"''.v:val.repeat(" ", maxlen-lengths[v:key]).''"''')` modifies an lines in a way you require. I switched from `printf` to `repeat` because printf does not handle multibyte characters correctly (by «correctly» I mean that «¥» is one character long, while printf considers it two bytes long).

`setlines(linenumber, listoflines)` actually modifies buffer.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you might `vmap` this?

Comment: @too much php `vnoremap \eq :<C-u>call Enquote()<CR>` to map this to `\eq` for visual mode. And omit using `*map` if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of the unix program "par" to do this may well solve your problem. There's a Vimcast showing how to integrate it into vim over at http://vimcasts.org/episodes/formatting-text-with-par/

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to make two passes over the list of lines in vim script?  Then you can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
let N = length of longest line
for each line L:
    insert a " character at the beginning
    append N - len(L) spaces
    append a " character
```

Answer (score 0):

best i got is a 3-pass regex.

select block in visual mode, then use:

```
:'<,'>s#^#"#
:'<,'>s#$#                                                #
:'<,'>s#\(.\{28\}\).*#\1"
```

with the 28 being the length of your longest line.

Answer (score 0):

By all means heed the previous answers and get your vim-fu in shape. Or install/modify/poke-the-author of this plugin:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4727

From the plugin's page:

> This script converts multi-line text in a C++ file to a multi-line
>   string literal, escaping the quote and tab characters. It also does
>   the reverse conversion, un-escaping some characters. It's not too
>   complete for now, but it will be someday if needs come.

If you need to make changes use the source-code repository:

https://bitbucket.org/dsign/stringliteral.vim

Answer (score -1):

In two passes:

```
let l = max(map(getline("'<", "'>"), 'strwidth(v:val)'))
'<,'>s/.*/\=('"'.submatch(0).repeat(' ', l-strwidth(submatch(0)) )).'"'
```

Comment: Replace `len(submatch)` with `len(split(submatch, '\zs'))` in order to handle multibyte strings. Do this with `len(v:val)` too.

Comment: 6 years latter note...: We can also use `strlen(substitute(submatch, '.', 'a', 'g'))` or simply `strdisplaywidth()` (or `strwidth()` if tab size doesn't matter) with recent versions of Vim.