# Emacs - fill a line with character X up to column Y

Tags: emacs

Is there an Emacs command that will "fill" a row with a particular character up to a specified column? Basically the equivalent of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364102/how-to-fill-a-line-with-character-x-up-to-column-y-using-vim), except with Emacs instead of Vim.

As an example, say I start entering lines that look like this:

```
/* -- Includes
/* -- Procedure Prototypes
/* -- Procedures
```

I'd like a command that automatically fills in the rest of the line (up to a column I can specify) with dashes, regardless of what column the cursor is currently on.

```
/* -- Includes -----------------------------------------------------
/* -- Procedure Prototypes -----------------------------------------
/* -- Procedures ---------------------------------------------------
```

Thank you. Sorry if this has been asked already, I couldn't find anything with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something which should work:

```
(defun fill-to-end ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (while (< (current-column) 80)
      (insert-char ?-))))
```

It appends `-` characters to the end of the current line until it reaches column 80. If you want to specify the character, it should be changed to

```
(defun fill-to-end (char)
  (interactive "cFill Character:")
  (save-excursion
    (end-of-line)
    (while (< (current-column) 80)
      (insert-char char))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun char-fill-to-col (char column &optional start end)
  "Fill region with CHAR, up to COLUMN."
  (interactive "cFill with char: \nnto column: \nr")
  (let ((endm  (copy-marker end)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (while (and (not (eobp))  (< (point) endm))
        (end-of-line)
        (when (< (current-column) column)
          (insert (make-string (- column (current-column)) char)))
        (forward-line 1)))))

(defun dash-fill-to-col (column &optional start end)
  "Fill region with dashes, up to COLUMN."
  (interactive "nFill with dashes up to column: \nr")
  (char-fill-to-col ?- column start end))
```